# Do I have to validate my 3-month ticket every time I board a bus in Warsaw?

Tags: public-transport, poland, warsaw

I moved to Warsaw, Poland, earlier this week and got myself a 3 months pre-paid ZTM card. However, none of the locals that board buses or trams with me seem to validate their cards or buy tickets onboard. So far I've only seen 1 or 2 people other than me actually use their card, and I've taken over 20 rides already.

Am I missing something here? Is it unnecessary to validate your card on every ride as long as it's not expired, or is there just a lot of people not paying for their ride?

Comment: What would be the point of validating a long term ticket?

Comment: @JonathanReez I came to Warsaw from Moscow, and you have to validate all tickets there, both long term and short term, even those that have expiry date five years into the future. I agree that it doesn’t make much sense, but it’s a thing.

Comment: Moscow isn't known for its public transport efficiency. They've only allowed all-door boarding in September 2018, so it would probably take another few years to stop requiring validations.

Comment: @JonathanReez In some countries it is required to build statistics of public transport usage.

Comment: @JonathanReez I know (experienced it first-hand, after all), but I don’t see how efficiency of public transportation system in Moscow is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that you have bought that ticket and it is stored on personalized card. From [ZTM's site (in English)](https://www.ztm.waw.pl/?c=110&l=2):

> 90-DAY TICKETS
>
> entitles to unlimited number of journeys from its [validation] until 23:59 of the ninetieth day of its validity

Now, the word "validation" is missing in original text, but it is mentioned in Polish version of the site.

That would mean, that you have to validate it only once, the first time you'd want to use it. Then, you don't have to validate on subsequent bus/tram rides. In subway you still need to use the card to enter a platform.

Comment: Also, if you hold the card against the ticket machine once it's validated, it will tell you how long you have until it expires.